# Django admin customization with non-related models

Tags: django

I am a django noob and am trying to figure out how to get the admin module to do something slightly different than the normal operation on a single model.  Essentially what I need is to run a query and display the results of the query as a view page and then allow the link to the edit page take the user to an existing model's edit view.  2 of the 3 tables in my query are related, but not all 3.

Example:

```
select a.foo, a.second_field, b.bar, c.unrelated_field
from a, b, c
where a.primary_key = b.foreign_key
and a.some_value = c.some_value
```

Note that a and c are not defined as related tables.

I would like to have a view of this query output and have a link to the edit view of the b model as a whole when selected.

I have created a view in the DB for this query and simply created a new model which makes it easy to get the view, but I'm not sure this is even the right approach to start with...but from there I can't seem to figure out how to make this link to the edit page for the B table.

Any pointers or advice on how best to accomplish something like this with django admin would be appreciated!

Using Django 1.3.1 by the way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `change_view` in your `ModelAdmin` so it will construct a list of dicts with all your needed data. Then override `change_list.html` template to display this data correctly and link it with `change_form` view for correct model. So it will flawlessly integrate in Django's admin site.

And I don't like DB views as long as it's possible to solve the problem without it. If data can be constructed in Python without massive performance gaps and lots of magic code, it should be processed in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am trying this now.  Two things...1) when you say construct a list of dicts, do you mean adding such to the extra_context?  I'm not 100% clear as to where these go.  Also I think I may still need the view as I want this to be separate from the standard model view for the specific model.  Although I am experimenting with adding a button or something to trigger my custom view (to your point about avoiding views where possible)

Comment: I've been wrong, method is `changelist_view`. Usually it uses [ChangeList](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1124) to display items, but you can send any other variable to the template, as long as your template knows what to do with it.